# zip files, zips the entire path

Tags: vb.net, command-line, zip

when i use winrar to zip a file, it for some reason zips the entire path. I am using vb.net for doing this.
here's the code -

```
  Public Sub RunArchive()
        Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        sPath = "C:\Users\images\"
        sArchive = "C:\Users\images\test"

        p.StartInfo.FileName = ("C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe")
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = (" a -ms*.rar;*.zip;*.jpg;*.xls " & sArchive & ".rar " & sPath & "s23.jpg")
        p.Start()
        p.WaitForExit()
    End Sub
```

its zips to th specified folder, but when i try to unzip it, i see the whole path form users to images to s23.jog is in there. Why is that? I only need s23.jog in there when i unzip it not the preceding folders.

Comment: This is more related to how `rar.exe` works, not quite a programming problem...

Comment: ya i know that, was hoping someone else had tried this before. I found the answer, needs an extra parameter in the arguments. Also if you dont know how to do something, just dont leave a comment for the heck of it.

Comment: It's a good question - and it's programming related. +1.

Comment: (" a ep- -ms*.rar;*.zip;*.jpg;*.xls " & sArchive & ".rar " & sPath & "s23.jpg") 
p.Start() 
Put ep- (exclude path) in the path and you're good to go

Comment: @refrefe You should make that comment the answer so this question doesn't show up in the unanswered list. (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)